# Orthogonality condition for momentum eigenfunction - integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration

Let's consider the orthonormality condition for an eigenfunction $\Psi_p(x)=(2 \pi \hbar)^{1/2}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} px}$ (plane wave) of the momentum operator with eigenvalue $p$.  Then the orthonormality condition says that the following must hold: $\int \Psi _p^*(x) \Psi_p'(x)dx = \delta(p-p')$ where $\delta$ denotes the Kronecker delta.
${Question}$: I tried to calculate this explicitly which leads me to $\int(2 \pi \hbar)^{-1}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} x(p'-p)} dx$. How do I have to proceed from here to get the condition mentioned above? To summarize the main problem is how to perform the last integral. What especially confuses me is that this is kind of a Fourier transform with some additional constants $\hbar.$

Comment: What you are referring to is a Dirac delta functions and not a Kronecker delta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one dimensional Fourier transform is defined as follows:

$\tilde{f}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{ikx}f(x)dx$

The inverse is then defined as

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-ikx}\tilde{f}(k)dk$

Now, substitute the second equation back into the first and introduce a dummy variable $x'$.

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-ikx}dk\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{ikx'}f(x')dx'$

After some simplification (note that the integral now represents a double integral)

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{ik(x'-x)}f(x') dk dx'$

But we have the definition of the delta function

$f(x) = \int \delta(x-x')f(x') d{x'}$

This naturally suggests
$\delta(x' - x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{ik(x'-x)}dk$

And this solves your problem with a change of variables. To see what happens to the delta function with an extra $\hbar$ or indeed any other factor, observe that
$\delta(x' - x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{ik(x'-x)}dk = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{i\frac{k}{\hbar}(x'-x)}d\frac{k}{\hbar}$

The limits are $\pm\infty$ so this is fine to do. Pull the $\hbar$ from $d\frac{k}{\hbar}$ out and you have

$\delta(x'-x) = \frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int e^{i\frac{k}{\hbar}(x'-x)}dk$